# How to free pointer memory inside a function?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, struct

I'm new to the use of pointers, and I'm trying to write a program to learn to use them. I have a question for you. I have a file `lib.h`, inside which I define all the functions necessary into the main. Inside this file I've a simple data `struct`:

```
struct Slave
{
    char **all_samples;
    int number_of_samples;
    char **last_samples;
    int *RSSI;
    int *AGC;
    int *AUTH;
};
```

As you can see, the members of this struct are pointers (pointers to int, pointers to pointers etc.). In the same file, I've several functions. Consider one of them, for simplicity. Inside this function, I read several lines from a file and put them into the array string `all_samples` (`i` is the number of lines previously correctly calculated):

```
struct Slave *read_slaves_file(char *file_path, char *slave)
{
    ...

    struct Slave *slave_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Slave *));
    slave_ptr->all_samples = malloc(i * sizeof(char *));
    slave_ptr->all_samples = all_samples;

    return slave_ptr;
}
```

I omitted the irrelevant part of code (my question is more theorical, I don't have bugs in my program). As you can see, I return a pointer to the struct, so, inside the main:

```
#include "lib.h"

int main(){

    struct Slave *slave_1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Slave *));
    slave_1 = read_slaves_file(FILE_PATH, SLAVE_1);

    return 0;
}
```

Everything seems to work fine...but, I have a doubt. All the memory dynamically allocated inside the previous function:

```
struct Slave *slave_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Slave *));
slave_ptr->all_samples = malloc(i * sizeof(char *));
```

Where should be deallocated? Should it be deallocated? I suppose I can't deallocate the memory before I return the pointer. So, how to do?

Comment: "I don't have bugs in my program). As you can see, I return a pointer to the struct, so, inside the main:"   `slave_1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Slave *)); slave_1 = /* blatant bug here */`

Comment: Add a free_slaves which will free the slave pointers and call it when you no longer need the pointers.

Comment: sure I can, but my question is: the only memory I have to free, is the memory for the pointers allocated inside the main? Only for them? Inside the function read_slaves_file as you can see I allocate memory for the struct and memory for its fields. This memory allocation does not need to be deallocated?

Comment: You should match every `malloc()` with a `free()` in reverse order. There is no automatic freeing of `struct` members which have an allocation when you free the struct itself.

Comment: yes, in fact my question is about that. How can I free the malloc inside the function is then I return the pointer to the struct?

Comment: In this faulty code you cannot, because you have overwritten the pointer obtained from `malloc` with something else.

Comment: is it enough to free the pointer inside the main? If I do: `struct Slave *slave_1 = read_slaves_file(FILE_PATH, SLAVE_1);`, then is enough to do `free(slave_1)`? Calling free only inside the main.

Comment: There is *no* automatic freeing of struct members which have an allocation when you free the struct itself.

Comment: Style suggestion, Although there are times where declaring struct members as pointers is very useful (eg when using the struct in the creation of a linked list), it would be less complicated to move as many pointers out to the instance of the struct itself as possible, for example instead of `struct st { int *var1; int *var2; int *var3; };` do this:  `struct st{int var1; int var2; int var3 };` Then create the instance as a pointer:   `struct st *pSt = NULL;`  Now you have only one allocation and free instead of three.

Comment: so in the main is correct (also if horrible design) to write: `free(slave_1); free(slave_1->all_samples) etc.`?

Comment: See my comment to the same question in the answer below.

Comment: No it isn't, please read the comments: *in reverse order*.

Comment: Aside: allocate to the referenced object size, not type.  `slave_ptr->all_samples = malloc(i * sizeof(char *));` --> `slave_ptr->all_samples = malloc(sizeof slave_ptr->all_samples[0] * i);`.  Certainly easier to review, and code right in the beginning and maintain.  This style would fix various allocation errors here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have bugs in my program

You have plenty of bugs.

- ```
  struct Slave *slave_1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Slave *));
  slave_1 = read_slaves_file(FILE_PATH, SLAVE_1);
  ```

  This reassigns `slave_1` creating a memory leak. It doesn't make sense  to allocate memory both in the caller and inside the function. Make up your mind where you want to do the allocation.
- `malloc(sizeof(struct Slave *))` This should be `malloc(sizeof(struct Slave))` or if you prefer `malloc(sizeof(*slave_1))`. The same bug exists in multiple places.
- `slave_ptr->all_samples = malloc(i * sizeof(char *));`
  `slave_ptr->all_samples = all_samples;`

  Same bug as before. By using the assignment operator, you either copy a pointer or copy data. It can't do both things unless you change the type of the operands. At this point I'd just back off from dynamic allocation and study how pointers work, particularly what's informally called "soft copy" vs "hard copy".

---

> Where should be deallocated?

The best option is always to have the caller do the allocation and make them provide a pointer to a buffer, for the function to fill up. This separates allocation from the algorithm. However, this might not always be an option.

Another good design is to have the code module which allocates something also take responsibility to clean up its own mess. So if your lib provides a function returning a pointer to dynamically allocated data, the same lib should also provide another function to clean up that data.

Some less well-designed functions return a pointer and expects the caller to clean it up (see for example POSIX `getline`). This is questionable but you can get away with it if you properly document that the caller is responsible for cleaning up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you're right, I realized the conceptual error I was doing inside the main with the memory allocation. But there is one thing I can't understand... after all the memory allocation I return the pointer to the struct. At this point, the function is terminated. How can deallocate the memory allocated by the function? I suppose I can't do it before I return the pointer...so, how to do it?

Comment: is it enought to free the pointer inside the main?

Comment: @LearningC As written in this answer, you have 3 different options.

Comment: is it enough to free the pointer inside the main? If I do: `struct Slave *slave_1 = read_slaves_file(FILE_PATH, SLAVE_1);`, then is enough to do `free(slave_1)`? Calling free only inside the main.

Comment: @LearningC Every `malloc` call must have a corresponding `free` call. In this case, expecting the caller to clean up a struct with nested levels of allocation is horrible design - provide a function that does the clean-up instead.

Comment: so in the main is correct (also if horrible design) to write: `free(slave_1); free(slave_1->all_samples) etc.`?

Comment: @LearningC -  In that last comment I believe you would want to switch the order in which those calls are made.  Once you free the struct, the memory allocated for its member is lost (a memory leak).  Free the members first, then free the struct.

Comment: You're right, thank you so much. For first I deallocate all the fields, the I deallocate the struct itself

Comment: "well-designed functions return a pointer and expects the caller to clean it up (see for example POSIX getline)" would benefit with re-wording as `getline()` returns an integer.